# Set full focus on a button (`SetFocus()` is not enough)

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to set true full focus on a push button (`button` window class) in WinAPI?

`SetFocus()` *somewhat* sets focus (the button gets an inner dotted border), but the button is actually *partially* focused and still cannot be pressed with the `Enter` key, only the `Spacebar` key works. At the same time, if I move focus to a sibling button with the `Tab` key, then this sibling button (as well as the first button if I then return focus to it using `Shift+Tab`) gets a *true* focus (visually, not just *inner* dotted focus border is added to the really focused button, but its main outer border becomes *blue* [Windows 7]), and now it reacts to `Enter` as intended.

How to make a button such *fully* focused programmatically?

Screenshot of the three button states:

[image: Screenshot of the three button states]

Some background for clarity: there is a window (created with the regular combination of `WNDCLASSEX` / `RegisterClassEx` / `CreateWindowEx()` with `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` as its style) with a multiline edit box (`edit` window class with `ES_MULTILINE` style) and several push buttons. To implement keyboard navigation using the `Tab` key, I process the `WM_KEYDOWN` event in the edit box's procedure (subclassed via `SetWindowLong()`), otherwise I could navigate between buttons and from buttons to the edit box, but not from the edit box to a button. All the controls have `WS_TABSTOP` style. The issue with the button focus takes place when I set focus using `SetFocus()` when the `Tab` key is pressed on the edit box having focus and caret.

Minimal relevant C++ code:

```
HWND mainWindow;
WNDPROC defaultEditCallback = NULL;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEXW wc;

    wchar_t windowClass[] = L"testcase";

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = mainWindowCallback;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = instance;
    wc.hIcon         = NULL;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)windowClass;
    wc.hIconSm       = NULL;

    RegisterClassExW(&wc);

    mainWindow = CreateWindowW(
        (LPCWSTR)windowClass, (LPCWSTR)windowClass, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 200, NULL, NULL, instance, NULL
    );

    HWND edit = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, (LPCWSTR)L"edit", NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | WS_TABSTOP,
        0, 0, 0, 0, mainWindow, (HMENU) 10,
        (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLongPtrW(mainWindow, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );

    defaultEditCallback = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtrW(edit, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG)editCallback);

    HWND firstButton  = createButton(mainWindow, 20, L"First",  buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    HWND secondButton = createButton(mainWindow, 30, L"Second", buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
    HWND thirdButton  = createButton(mainWindow, 40, L"Third",  buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

    // [Skipped] Sizing and positioning controls.

    ShowWindow(mainWindow, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(mainWindow);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        if (!IsDialogMessage(mainWindow, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK mainWindowCallback(HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (WM_DESTROY == msg) {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(window, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK editCallback(HWND control, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (WM_KEYDOWN == msg && VK_TAB == wParam) {
        HWND next = GetNextDlgTabItem(mainWindow, control, (int)(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000));
        SetFocus(next);
        return 0;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(defaultEditCallback, control, msg, wParam, lParam);
}


HWND createButton(HWND parentWindow, int id, wchar_t* caption, int width, int height) {
    return CreateWindowW(
        (LPCWSTR)L"button", (LPCWSTR)caption, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
        0, 0, width, height, parentWindow, (HMENU)id, NULL, NULL
    );
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: We cannot see your code, but nothing as "full focus" not exists. Only control has focus or not.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why the state two (partially focused, the actual result of `SetFocus()`) is different from the state three (fully focused, the expected/desired result). The difference itself certainly exists, both in terms of apperarance and in terms of behavior, that's why I've asked the question here.

Comment: Nothing as "partially focused" not exists. What you see is button painted with DrawFocusRect() without visual style. Again nobody see your code!

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks, but I have multiple buttons, no one of them should be default. Or do you mean to dynamically make each focused button the default button at the same time? I thought of this as a possible workaround before posting the question. Or is this the way it's naturally implemented when tabbing between buttons?

Comment: Focus and default button go hand in hand but they are not the same thing. The button with focus will get keyboard input - e.g. the space bar will activate it. The default button is the one that's activated when you push return. The dialog itself manages the default button, which is why you need to send `DM_SETDEFID` to the dialog if you want to change it. This isn't a "workaround", it's how you are supposed to do it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks. Unfortunately, `DM_SETDEFID` (`SendMessageW(mainWindow, DM_SETDEFID, buttonId, 0)`) did not change anything. What looks like has helped is setting dynamically the button's style to `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` in combination with regular `SetFocus()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question does not make it clear whether the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` main window is either a dialog, or subclassed to work like a dialog (i.e. based on `DefDlgProc`). Some hints about TAB navigation and DM_SETDEFID in the OP and following comments appear to indicate that it's a dialog(-styled) window.

For dialogs, the correct way to move the input focus between child controls is by sending the [WM_NEXTDLGCTL message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645432.aspx), rather than calling `SetFocus` directly. As noted in the docs:

> This message performs additional dialog box management operations beyond those performed by the SetFocus function WM_NEXTDLGCTL updates the default pushbutton border, sets the default control identifier, and automatically selects the text of an edit control (if the target window is an edit control).

More details at [How to set focus in a dialog box](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040802-00/?p=38283), including this part:

> As the remarks to the DM_SETDEFID function note, messing directly with the default ID carelessly can lead to odd cases like a dialog box with two default buttons. Fortunately, you rarely need to change the default ID for a dialog.
>
> A bigger problem is using SetFocus to shove focus around a dialog. If you do this, you are going directly to the window manager, bypassing the dialog manager. This means that you can create “impossible” situations like having focus on a pushbutton without that button being the default!
>
> To avoid this problem, don’t use SetFocus to change focus on a dialog. Instead, use the WM_NEXTDLGCTL message.

---

[EDIT]  After the OP edit, the main window turns out to be a regular window, not a dialog. The newly posted code, however, does not remember the focused child (nor does it remove/restore the default pushbutton style) after the main window is deactivated and reactivated, relegates keyboard navigation such as VK_TAB to child controls etc. Those introduce inconsistencies with the default dialog-like behaviors.

In order to make the main window behave *like* a dialog (and do it right), the WNDPROC would need to mimic the relevant parts of DefDlgProc,  at least those that pertain to navigation. From [Dialog Box Programming Considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644995.aspx), among the messages such a WNDPROC would need special handling for are `DM_GETDEFID`, `DM_SETDEFID`, `WM_ACTIVATE`, `WM_NEXTDLGCTL`, `WM_SHOWWINDOW`, `WM_SYSCOMMAND`. Once that's done, my original answer still applies.

Comment: Thanks, but looks like `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` (`PostMessage(mainWindow, WM_NEXTDLGCTL, TRUE, FALSE)`, same for `SendMessage(...)`) does not do anything in my case. Fwiw, my window is created with the regular combination of `WNDCLASSEX`  / `RegisterClassEx` / `CreateWindowEx()` with `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` as its style; I suspect this is not a dialog.

Comment: @user5994649 See the docs, you probably want `PostMessage(mainWindow, WM_NEXTDLGCTL, hwndControlToReceiveFocus, TRUE)` instead. As for the main window, it is technically possible (though uncommon) that it would processes dialog-specific messages without being a dialog itself, but it's hard to guess what's going on since you showed no code. Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then post the necessary code.

Comment: Does not work either. I'm aware of that a minimal testcase is desirable, but with C++/WinAPI that's somewhat problematic. I've purposely described the issue in detail to probably get a feedback from those encountered exactly the same issue (I'm surely not the only one in the world that has encountered it).

Comment: @user5994649 You **really** need to stop saying "does not work" without posting code. All the advice you've been given is correct.

Comment: Not providing a [mcve] is not good enough. It's simple to do here. Describing your code leaves room for miscommunication. We've seen it time and again and are bored by the issue. Post an MCVE if you really do want help.

Comment: @dxiv, @JonathanPotter, @DavidHeffernan Actually, as I already said, I've already found a sort of solution (different from what has been proposed here), so creating minimal code (which is quite time consuming) is basically unneeded. But why not? After all, that was interesting and I'm now sure other parts of my program have nothing to do with the issue. ;-) I've added the relevant code. Please note that the code is minimal, so some nested functions are merged, single-`case` `switch`es are replaced with `if`, HiDPI scaling removed, etc.

Comment: @user5994649 So your code has immediately made it clear that you do not have a dialog. These details make a difference.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I believe I've provided enough details in the original question text + first comment to this dxiv's answer (and a subsequent corresponding question edit). But anyway, you wanted code, you've got the code. If needed, I could provide the whole compilable program (126 lines), but provided the smaller relevant part (84 lines) for now.

Comment: Ok, marking this as answer. Though I'm going to use another approach (handle focus and default style of the button manually) for now, I'm now at least know that "full" focus is actually focus in conjunction with the default-button _style_ (`BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`, for regular windows) or marking the button as default for the window (`DM_SETDEFID`, for dialog windows). Thanks for the help, guys.